# Attempt to read property "id" on null In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm going to update the SEO as admin from the frontend it shows me the error

> Attempt to read property "id" on null

[image]

This is my controller code

```
public function updateSEO(Request $request)
    {
        // first, get the language info from db
        $language = Language::where('code', $request->language)->first();
        $langId = $language->id;

        // then, get the seo info of that language from db
        $seo = SEO::where('language_id', $langId)->first();

        // else update the existing seo info of that language
        $seo->update($request->all());

        $request->session()->flash('success', __('Updated successfully!'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

This is my view code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ __('Meta Description For Home Page') }}</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="home_meta_description" rows="5"
        placeholder="{{ __('Enter Meta Description') }}">{{ $data->home_meta_description }}</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is in this line

```
 $language = Language::where('code', $request->language)->first();
```

before using the **$language** first check if the above return any data or not when it doesn't return something then it will show error
do like this try this code hope you get

```
if($language){

   $langId = $language->id; 
}else{
  echo 'no data found';
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Yeah It's not able to get the $language and that's why it prints "no data found".
Could you please suggest how can I get the $language?

Comment: For that i need the request and the function you call then i can help

Answer (score 0):

1. Use early exit
2. You may use session flash message like success,error and warning.

```
    public function updateSEO(Request $request)
    {
        // first, get the language info from db
        $language = Language::where('code', $request->language)->first();
        if($language === null) {
            $request->session()->flash('error', __('No Language found!'));

            return redirect()->back();
        }
        $langId = $language->id;

        // then, get the seo info of that language from db
        $seo = SEO::where('language_id', $langId)->first();

        // else update the existing seo info of that language
        $seo->update($request->all());

        $request->session()->flash('success', __('Updated successfully!'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```